# downloading dynamic webcontent through Scrapy (python 2.7)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've came back to this project (web scraping dynamic content) and I followed through with this tutorial, however I cannot complete it.

I am using python 2.7 with the [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) framework 0.14

With my project, getting data is obviously the most important point, I am coming to understand the technique to scraping sites that pull down dynamic data with ajax, however in this example I am unable to actually download the images.

The scraper runs with the command (in cmd.exe on windows 7):

> scrapy runspider nasa.py

but it does not actually download anything (it only parses the data)

Am I missing something? This is the first real programming project where I have ventured out into non-beginner territory and am certainly getting lost.

This is the tutorial:

[Scraping ajax with Scrapy](http://blog.scrapy.org/scraping-ajax-sites-with-scrapy)

Any advice on the correct code to allow the script to download images to local storage?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your setting.py

add

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'you dir path where you want to download images'
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline'] #enable image pipline
```

in your item define **image_urls**

add images urls your in **image_urls** # should be treated as a list in your program

[suggested study](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html)